# Looking for match between my laptop and linux kernel

Tags: debian, linux-kernel

I have a "LENOVO Ideapad 300-14IBR 80M2".
The basic debian install failed on me. (many problems : wifi, suspend, gpu, various crashes...)
I randomly used `jessie-backport` and `non-free`, compiling and installing some linux kernels as well.

```
#dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64              3.16.36-1+deb8u1                     amd64        Linux 3.16 for 64-bit PCs
ii  linux-image-4.2.1-040201-generic        4.2.1-040201.201509211431            amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.2.1 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.13                      1.0.NAS                              amd64        Linux kernel binary image for version 4.4.13
ii  linux-image-4.5.0-0.bpo.2-amd64         4.5.4-1~bpo8+1                       amd64        Linux 4.5 for 64-bit PCs
ii  linux-image-4.6.0                       1.0.NAS                              amd64        Linux kernel binary image for version 4.6.0
ii  linux-image-4.6.0-0.bpo.1-amd64         4.6.3-1~bpo8+1                       amd64        Linux 4.6 for 64-bit PCs
ii  linux-image-amd64                       3.16+63                              amd64        Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
```

With `linux-image-4.2.1-040201-generic` the GPU is working a little. (less charge on cpu on video play... but suspend, hibernate just crash the computer)

I obviously have no idea what I am doing, but it's a good time for me to learn.
My main problem is with my GPU :

```
 #lspci -vnn | grep VGA
 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:22b1] (rev 21) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

How can i find the best kernel for my system based on a specific hardware ?
Do I need to compile it myself or is there a trustable kernel source with a gpu/driver inside ?

now my `/etc/apt/sources.list` :

```
deb ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

Thanks.

Comment: When was your laptop manufactured? What release (Jessie / stable, Stretch / testing) did you try to install? Have you tried the latest kernel from backports (4.7)?  What does "basic install failed on me" mean? Was the install successful but some components didn't work, or did the installer crash?

Comment: Try going with Debian 9/ stretch. Avoid buying Lenovo. They whitelist and change manuf  IDs of internal hardware cards.